# Is there a way to run a self-terminating js script that can pass variables to the next?

Tags: node.js, security, environment-variables, secret-key

I'd really like to have some of my my secrets/keys be iterable, since I have a growing list of external api keys that would be easier to use if I could match them based on the route being used without having to statically map them at the start of my application.

The only way I can think to better organize them without writing massive JSON one-line strings in a batch/bash file would be to have it all defined in js object literals and have a js script stringify it and load it into ENV variables to be passed to the application that's about to start.

NPM pre-start script:

```js
const env = {
  secret: 'supersecret',
  key: `key
  that requires
  line breaks`,
  apiKeys: {
    'api-1':'a;sodhgfasdgflksdaj;lg',
    'api-2':'ajl;sdfj;adjsfkljasd;f'
  }
}

for (let x in env) {
  if (typeof env[x] == 'string') {
    process.env[x] = env[x];
  } else {
    process.env[x] = JSON.stringify(env[x])
  }
  console.log(x)
}

process.exit(22);
```

NPM start script:

```js
const key = process.env.key
const apiKeys = JSON.parse(process.env.apiKeys)
```

Unfortunately, the ENV variables don't remain between instances, so this is useless.

Would it also be secure to use STDIN and STDOUT to pass the data between the two scripts?

Comment: Doesn't this scenario call for a JSON config file that you can then dynamically read from your code.  Not sure why you feel like it has to be in environment variables.

Comment: @jfriend00 Not necessarily, like stdin I mentioned. But a json file would be in the same directory and would be harder to isolate permissions for.

Comment: A JSON file can be located anywhere you want.  It doesn't have to be in the same directory as you code.  I guess I don't follow the logic of the question.  You're going to be reading these values from a file somewhere.  I don't see why you have to read them from the file, then put them somewhere else (in the environment on in stdin) and then let the program read them rather than just having the program read them directly from the config file where they're originally stored.

Comment: If it's reading it directly then that means the application has read access on it, if it's something else then it can just be the process manager that has permissions on it. I suppose I was hoping I could load it in such that the secrets and their origin are invisible or obscured to all but the scopes that need it.

Comment: Well, some sort of launch manager can stick a chunk of JSON in stdio and then your server could read it from there (and have no idea where it came from).  I don't really see myself how that's more secure, but you could certainly do that.

Comment: That's true, I just realized the benefit to using a js file is that it will will be platform independent since node is a pre-req anyways (no need for `cat txt` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being to pipe output by converting to JSON then streaming to STDOUT and receiving on STDIN on the second script. Doing this made it platform agnostic and I can add any sort of active secret management in the source script (e.g. accepting secrets from various other secret management systems/vaults or generating new secrets at every launch)

Send to STDOUT:

```js
const env = {
   someSecret: 'supersecret',
   superSecretObject: {
      moreProperties: 'data'
   }
};
/* If you have an array of properties or have a very large set of secrets, 
you should create a readable stream from it, and send that to stdout, 
but this is much simpler */
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(env));
```

Accept on STDIN:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const env = (function () {
/* Using fs will error out on no input, but you can use process.stdin 
   if you don't need to suspend the whole application waiting for the input */
    let envTmp = fs.readFileSync(0).toString();
    envTmp = JSON.parse(envTmp);
    return envTmp;
})();
```